# Pass variable from Web-Application to Service

Tags: c#, variables, web-applications, service

I have a web-application and a running Service. The Service starts an exe at a certain time. I want to write the start time into a textbox and than it should be passed to the service. Is this possible and if it is how? Do I have to stop the service to pass the information?

Comment: Depends on how/where you are running the two things. But you'd need some kind of message broker in between to notify each other.

Comment: Both runs on the same server.

Comment: You'd need to look at one of the queueing system. Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076790/the-bare-minimum-needed-to-write-a-msmq-sample-application. This queueing system will help you communicate between the two systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.
You have to use a wcf Service for the inter process communication.
The Service does not Need to stop.

I recommend that you take a look at wcf and do some tutorials on asp.net. In most asp.net tutorials they Show how you can attach textboxes to a model.