# MSMQ for multiple clients in C# application

Tags: c#, msmq

I am new to MSMQ in C#.

This is the requirement: I have one application to publish the message which need to be subscribed by multiple applications.

The problem I am facing is only one client is able to get message, but other clients are not. Please help me how I can achieve that.

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you have tried and where you think the issue might be, we can then analyse your subscription logic, and receiving logic to point you in the right direction. (show both the publisher code and the client code)

Comment: Have a look at this post for additional guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076790/the-bare-minimum-needed-to-write-a-msmq-sample-application

Comment: You can try using NServiceBus for this? https://docs.particular.net/get-started/

Comment: Sounds like the clients are coded to receive the message rather than peek it.